# Extracting the data from a csv file amd making dictionary of it using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file like this:

```
001,citycode,countrycode,usacode,usacountrycode
00457,citycode,countrycode,ugandacode,kampalacode
00976,countrycode,dubaicode,uaecode,dubaiareacode
```

How can I make a dictionary of this data like this:

```
data_dict = {'001' : ['citycode', 'countrycode', 'usacode', 'usacountrycode'],
             '00457' : ['citycode', 'countrycode', 'ugandacode', 'kampalacode'],
             '00976' : ['countrycode', 'dubaicode', 'uaecode', 'dubaiareacode']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a `csv` module, the documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
>>> import csv
>>> your_dict = {}
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         your_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```